# How to pass more than one argument from `find -exec` to a `bash -c` sub-shell?

Tags: bash, find, subshell

Is there a way to pass more than one argument from `find -exec` to a `bash -c` sub-shell?

Given this working invocation which searches all videos matching a glob pattern (eg `"*dogs.mp4`) and then executing `ffmpeg` in a sub-shell with a check and warning in case the file already exists:

```bsh
find . -iname "*.mp4" -exec bash -c 'if [[ -f "${1%.*}_540.mp4" ]]; then echo "Already exists: $1"; else ffmpeg -i "$1" -vf "scale=540:-1" "${1%.*}_540.mp4" ; fi ;' _ {} +
```

In order to avoid hard-coding the size I replaced `540` with `$2` and then pass the size as parameter after `{}` (to `_ {} 540 +`) so that the command becomes:

```bsh
find . -iname "*.mp4" -exec bash -c 'if [[ -f "${1%.*}_$2.mp4" ]]; then echo "Already exists: $1"; else ffmpeg -i "$1" -vf "scale=%2:-1" "${1%.*}_%2.mp4" ; fi ;' _ {} 540 +
```

The line above throws an error: `find: -exec: no terminating ";" or "+"`:

My understanding is that `{}` is the placeholder for the file name and `{} +` (or `{} \;`) must be at the end of the command.

In this scenario how to pass an additional parameter to `bash -c` from the `-exec` clause?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't put an argument *after* the `{}` if you're using `+`; check [the spec](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/find.html):

> -exec ... Only a plus-sign that immediately follows an argument containing only the two characters "{}" shall punctuate the end of the primary expression. Other uses of the plus-sign shall not be treated as special.

Also, you are passing multiple args to the shell (using +) but only using `$1` which means you're ignoring the rest of the files found.  You need to put a loop inside your shell command.  See https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/321753/135943 for some examples, but overall it looks like:

```
find dirname ... -exec sh -c 'for f do somecommandwith "$f"; done' placeholder {} +
```

And you are "hard-coding" the size anyway.  You may as well hardcode it in the actual shell command; it's easier then hardcoding it in the parameter list at the end.  But if you insist, you could pass `540` *in place of* your underscore (i.e. in place of the "placeholder" in the above command), and access it at `$0` from inside the shell command.

---

For the more general question, how to pass additional args to a shell command embedded in a `find ... -exec` command when you're passing all the found files to the shell command and want to process them in a loop, it can be done like so:

```
find dirname ... -exec sh -c 'arg1="$1"; arg2="$2"; shift 2; for f do somecommandwith "$f" "$arg1" "$arg2"; done' placeholder firstextraarg secondextraarg {} +
```

But the real question is, *why would you want to do that?*  You can much more easily put the "firstextraarg" and "secondextraarg" values directly inside the shell command:

```
find dirname ... -exec sh -c 'for f do somecommandwith "$f" firstextraarg secondextraarg; done' placeholder {} +
```

Comment: if the statement is terminated with `{} \;` then there is no need to loop over matches inside the subshell. `+` does some kind of speed optimization and in this specific case with `+` the subshell is **not** getting called for each single match

Comment: @ccpizza right, that's the purpose of the `+`.  If you don't want multiple files passed to the command for each invocation you shouldn't be using `+`.  See the spec (I provided the link) and search for "-exec" and you'll find this.

Comment: Thanks for confirming! in fact, I'll change it to `find ... -print0 | xargs-0 ...` so that it doesn't break with funny file names

Comment: @ccpizza `find ... -exec ... {} +` is completely safe from breakage regardless of special filenames but okay.  (If that surprises you see additional background in http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/321697/135943)